# How to convert nested lists of unknown number to a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm reading data from CSV files and I'm getting lists with a variable number of sublists that look like this:

```
list = [
    ["a","b","c"],
    ["aa","bb","cc"],
    ["11","22","33"],
    ......
]
```

the list doesn't have to have 3 sublists, but the sublists always have the same amount of values between each other

This is the only way I'm able to access this data because of an existing method. I have no idea how to zip or create a dict in this case.

I want to get a dict like this:

```
dict = {
   'a' : ['aa','11'],
   'b' : ['bb','22'],
   'c' : ['cc','33'],
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried *anything* to accomplish this, and if so, what?

Comment: If using an external package is okay for your case, consider using `pandas` which gives an easy way to read a csv into a `DataFrame` which has a method [`.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generalizing @GrajdeanuAlex.'s solution:

```
{item[0]: list(item[1:]) for item in zip(*list)}
```

Answer (score 0):

For one, it's not a good idea to name variables that conflict with builtins like `list` or `dict`, but this will work for any amount of sublists.

```
dict = {list[0][i]: [list[x][i] for x in range(1,len(list))] for i in range(len(list))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to do this.This is my code

```
List = [ ['a','b','c'], ['aa','bb','cc' ], ['11','22','33'],....]
L = len(List[0])
Dict = {}
for j in range(L):
   Lt = [i[j] for i in List]
   Dict[Lt[0]] = Lt[1:]
print(Dict)
```